# Memory leaks in boost threads?

Tags: c++, boost, memory-leaks, valgrind

I'm trying out boost threads and I noticed from valgrind that it is leaking 320 bytes just from looping through an empty block of code. I found some posts on google from 2010 that suggests that they are likely a false positive from threads not closing before valgind runs through, but this is slightly different. In those examples you had a few blocks that were still reachable (therefor, freeable if threads were still running) where my run shows 8 as still reachable and 20 blocks as definitely lost. Is this something I should worry about, or am I somehow missing something? Thanks

The code

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#define THREADS 20

void threadfunc(int workerid) {}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    boost::thread *threads[THREADS];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < THREADS; i++) {
        threads[i] = new boost::thread(threadfunc, i);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < THREADS; i++) {
        threads[i]->join();
    }
}
```

Compile command

```
 c++ -o example example.cpp -I /usr/include/boost -lboost_system -lboost_thread
```

Valgind command

```
 G_SLICE=always-malloc G_DEBUG=gc-friendly  valgrind -v --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes --num-callers=40 --log-file=valgrind.log ./example
```

Valgine results

```
==31674== HEAP SUMMARY:
==31674==     in use at exit: 328 bytes in 21 blocks
==31674==   total heap usage: 103 allocs, 82 frees, 14,968 bytes allocated
==31674==
==31674== Searching for pointers to 21 not-freed blocks
==31674== Checked 215,920 bytes
==31674==
==31674== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 2
==31674==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==31674==    by 0x4E454A9: boost::detail::get_once_per_thread_epoch() (in /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.46.1)
==31674==    by 0x4E3E4FF: ??? (in /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.46.1)
==31674==    by 0x4E3E7C8: boost::detail::get_current_thread_data() (in /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.46.1)
==31674==    by 0x4E3FF3A: boost::thread::join() (in /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.46.1)
==31674==    by 0x402C79: main (in /home/Jason/php/base/example)
==31674==
==31674== 320 bytes in 20 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==31674==    at 0x4C2B1C7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==31674==    by 0x402C2A: main (in /home/Jason/php/base/example)
==31674==
==31674== LEAK SUMMARY:
==31674==    definitely lost: 320 bytes in 20 blocks
==31674==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31674==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31674==    still reachable: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
==31674==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31674==
==31674== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
--31674--
--31674-- used_suppression:      2 dl-hack3-cond-1
==31674==
==31674== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

Comment: The 8 bytes of "still reachable" is something I have seen on every valgrind run that used boost-thread. So, I think that's normal (probably something they had to do), and it doesn't seem to depend or grow with the number of threads, it's probably some unique global data that is not freed (on purpose). That memory will be reclaimed anyways, so it is of no real concern. For the other 20 "definitely lost" blocks, well, that's obviously the lack of `delete` calls for those 20 threads, as ForEveR pointed out.

Comment: Thanks, and no it doesn't seem grow. I ran a test yesterday threading PHP's core and after recreating those 10 threads over a thousand times and 3,000,000+ allocations (yes, thats 6 zeros) that one 8 byte block was the only problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's your errors, not `boost::thread`s.
Your memory are not freed.

```
for (i = 0; i < THREADS; i++) {
    threads[i] = new boost::thread(threadfunc, i);
}
```

Before exit from main function you must free memory (delete threads).
Something like

```
for (i = 0; i < THREADS; i++) {
   delete threads[i];
}
```

or delete next after join.

Comment: I almost fell on my sword over that one. This proves that even coffee cant keep us going after 30 hours lol

Comment: I have the same problem.  With the "*_epoch" function.  However, I don't new boost::thread.  My threads are allocated on the stack in main.  I join them, then return from main.  I'm wondering if you know of anyway to remove this error (aside from suppression).  It appears to be coming from boost, but -ofcourse- it could also be something I am doing.